# Can only SSH into Raspberry Pi from Ethernet cable

Tags: wifi

So, I've ran `arp -a` in raspberry pi and it shows some addresses:

```
    ? (10.50.220.1) at 00:14:a9:d0:72:80 [ether] on wlan0
    ? (10.50.221.198) at 48:5a:b6:6d:07:ef [ether] on wlan0
    ? (10.42.0.1) at 5c:f9:dd:3f:f9:27 [ether] on eth0
    ? (10.50.220.250) at 70:18:8b:0e:a2:71 [ether] on wlan0
```

If I try to ping any of those addresses, it works. If I try to ssh, it fails. Also, I tried `ifconfig wlan0,` which returns a ip address that doesn't exist:

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:da:38:5c:7b:01  
          inet addr:10.50.221.13  Bcast:10.50.223.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::76da:38ff:fe5c:7b01/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3319 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:710 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:373186 (364.4 KiB)  TX bytes:79057 (77.2 KiB)
```

When I try to ping ip address `10.50.221.13` from another terminal it fails:

```
PING 10.50.221.13 (10.50.221.13) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.50.221.249 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.50.221.249 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.50.221.249 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.50.221.249 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.50.221.249 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.50.221.249 icmp_seq=6 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 10.50.221.13 ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 0 received, +6 errors, 100% packet loss, time 6029ms
pipe 3
```

Here is the output of `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet dhcp

# The wifi (wireless) network interface
auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
     wpa-ssid "optix"
     wpa-psk "XXXX"
```

When I use the app Fing on my phone, it doesn't show that ip address either.

The Raspberry Pi has a Edimax N150 Wi-Fi Nano USB Adapter on it. I only have managed to connect via an ethernet cable.

This may not be the same as other questions, as far as I can tell.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could give me some other things to look into.

Comment: It would be helpful if you listed the outputs of the commands you tried and the `/etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: You appear to be having a discussion with yourself in Comments. Delete these. It is difficult to comment on your `interfaces` file - it may work, but doesn't look like any other. See http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697 and restore your files to standard settings. The `arp` output is pretty meaningless without knowledge of your network architecture.

Comment: It is WPA Personal. I can't tell you any more about the network architecture, unfortunately because I do not have administrative access to it. I suspect that they block ssh to internal locations (but not to external locations).

Comment: @Milliways it appears the wpa_supplicant.conf is corrupted or something.

Comment: Could you show us the contents of the `wpa_supplicant.conf`file and, as it isn't your own network, remember to **hide any sensitive passwords/keys**...!

Answer (score 1):

This is because `WLAN` is in different subnet than `ETH`...

Check your wifi ip and netmask:

`10.50.221.13 / 255.255.252.0`

That subnet doesn't contain the ethernet ip address: `10.42.0.1`.

In fact, because of that mask, your wlan subnet contains ips:

`10.50.220.1` to `10.50.223.254` or something like that (same count of ips).

You can check out [this tool](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/SubnetCalculator.jsp?ipAddress=10.50.221.13&cidr=22), if you don't know anything about netmasks.

How to fix that? Well... The easiest way would be to setup wifi router, so it would assign adresses from same subnet (10.42.x.*), not (10.50.x.*), for example:

`10.42.0.128 - 10.42.0.254`

and ethernet to

`10.42.0.1 - 10.42.0.127`

or simply change ethernet ip, so it would be in range:

`10.50.220.1 to 10.50.223.254`

Comment: Setting up a wifi router is not an option for me, considering I live at a student apartment complex that provides wifi.